# Differences between Woocommerce Prices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, price

Can someone tell me what are the differences between:

- `_price`
- `_sale_price`
- `_regular_price`

Answer (score 1):

_price : the active price; if product is on discount it stores `_sale_price` else `_regular_price`

_sale_price : stores product sale price if product is set to discount

_regular_price : stores product regular price

Answer (score 0):

Regular price is the normal price that is set for the product.

When you wish to offer a discount directly to the product it could be labelled as a Sale price

Answer (score 0):

- **Price**: The price you want to list your product.
- **Regular Price**: At which similar products are sold in the market
- **Sale Price**: It is the price on which you have offered a discount